# redirection of a addon domain (and all urls) using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, add-on

Ok, I've done a bunch a reading, as well as playing around, but I cannot solve this .htaccess problem.

I have an addon domain to my main hosting account.  I've managed to have the root addon domain go to a specific file using the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?addondomain.org$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /new-index.php [L]
```

That's all well and good; however, if someone tries to access the addon domain at any other URL than the root, and that page does not exist, then a 404 pops up. So, if I go to addondomain/car.php a 404 will display.

I would like all 404 errors for the addon domain - and ONLY for the addon domain - to also display the new-index.php file.

The ErrorDocument 404 /new-index.php command isn't an option because then it impacts both the main domain, as well as the addon domain.

Put differently: I want any URL for the addon domain to point to /new-index.php.

Thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Well, `^(www.)?addondomain.org$` obviously matches only for the domain itself or with www. in front of it. If you want it to match other domains, modify this regular expression accordingly.

Comment: No, I don't want to match *other* domains - I want to redirect all URLS of the addon domain - so... addondomain.org/cars.php and addondomain.org both point to the same file.

Comment: Well then you have to add RewriteConds to check whether the request matches an existing file or directory to determine if it'll be a 404 or not, and then redirect only if not ... http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: And would you mind helping on that?  I've tried over and over and I cannot figure out how to write the statement(s). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match all URL paths, then you must use a regular expression, which matches everything. Use `.*` or `^` for example

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new-index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?addondomain.org$
RewriteRule ^ /new-index.php [L]
```

Comment: I only want to match the URLS of the addon domain, so what would that look like?

Comment: @user2155255 As you already have it, just replace the `RewriteRule`. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. When I tried using the new code you suggested, it caused a 500 error. Thoughts?

Comment: @user2155255 I forgot to exclude `new-index.php` from the rewrite rule. Please see updated answer.